# Why is a shared pointer used for the string if the function call results in pass by reference?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, boost-smart-ptr

In this boost async udp server example:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6/src.html

```
  boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message(
      new std::string(make_daytime_string()));

  socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*message), remote_endpoint_,
      boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_send, this, message,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_send_to/overload1.html

the signature of 1st argument is pass by reference

```
const ConstBufferSequence & buffers
```

then why is a shared pointer used for the message to be send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the string is not just passed as the first argument to `async_send_to()`, but it is also used in the `bind()` expression that is being passed to `async_send_to()` as the *third* argument.

Function `handle_send()` expects a `shared_ptr` to a `string`. Since the call is asynchronous, a `string` object with automatic storage duration may have fallen out of scope and get destroyed by the time `handle_send()` gets executed. Hence, the use of a `shared_ptr`.